# Counting sheets viewer

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How do I use Google Apps Script to find out how many "current viewer" and their status, such as 'idle' or not.

I've already search thru all the question and answer, but only found how to display current user only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's not possible.

Google Apps Script has methods to get the active user and the effective user. Both of them should have edit access to the spreadsheet, the first is the editor that has opened the spreadsheet and caused that the script be executed, the second is the user that created the installable trigger that called the current execution.

P.S. You might see the file activity on the Google Sheets UI. For details see [View the activity on your Google Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739?hl=en)

Related (Stack Overflow)

- [Getting a list of active file viewers with apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39602639/1595451)